# Using column name passed to function in ggplot aes, data.frame, and nls

Tags: r

OK, let's say I have the following data in a CSV file ("example_data.csv"):

```
Likelihood,Weight,Par1,Par2,Par3
0.186844384,0.036923697,2,2,58
0.533218654,0.501397958,0,0,65
0.242303977,0.003077206,1,1,46
0.345092541,0.444826685,2,2,23
0.293672855,0.108440953,2,3,29
0.287151901,0.788640671,2,2,45
0.662063373,0.995332406,-1,-2,71
0.515526137,0.089007922,-1,-1,110
0.330131798,0.419704507,1,1,43
0.340537446,0.384904805,-1,-1,78
0.42350387,0.817862511,0,0,94
0.278387583,0.912293985,1,2,53
0.413520775,0.465414836,1,1,56
0.111797213,0.276860883,3,3,26
0.420515164,0.642712917,1,1,68
0.30835086,0.882109026,1,1,24
0.576850063,0.518219853,0,-2,81
0.355660735,0.790567044,0,0,29
0.979357518,0.039895315,-4,-4,177
0.656909082,0.404682824,-2,-4,101
0.48684488,0.488388762,-2,-3,144
0.806577308,0.530345186,-2,-3,143
0.658578518,0.970476957,-2,-5,160
0.521646556,0.723287454,2,3,83
0.60702761,0.727149894,-2,-4,155
0.694971183,0.071413935,3,4,22
0.351835995,0.98549942,-1,-1,81
0.916744944,0.867929188,-1,-2,91
0.646122983,0.395781956,-1,-2,95
0.292583756,0.907615016,-1,-1,89
0.500997719,0.7635543,-2,-4,142
0.827681213,0.094512069,-2,-5,149
0.904759491,0.374158994,-3,-4,97
0.783803411,0.962195178,-3,-4,102
0.382691023,0.41835611,0,0,21
0.290186245,0.842489929,2,2,10
0.417623103,0.413883742,-3,-4,145
0.813249374,0.265328688,-2,-3,102
0.882071817,0.817630957,-2,-4,99
0.849050068,0.101411688,-2,-2,61
0.390254013,0.637964495,1,1,22
0.243507734,0.070444932,2,3,15
0.259785717,0.501507883,2,2,5
0.685399514,0.347204068,-3,-5,152
0.483162564,0.724026851,-3,-4,121
0.828930794,0.71894471,0,-1,50
0.282705441,0.551101402,1,1,21
0.09732417,0.113851154,3,4,29
0.22818404,0.000950461,1,1,32
0.132510088,0.654162829,0,0,58
0.229581317,0.099388171,1,2,99
0.768479467,0.014822263,-2,-3,126
0.572649738,0.465394695,-1,-1,107
0.195123412,0.677059169,0,0,64
0.602264748,0.128128995,-1,-1,112
0.566370697,0.454819417,-3,-5,180
0.962733978,0.909347539,-5,-3,215
0.762192377,0.840566094,-3,-4,194
0.909048091,0.146816754,-2,-4,205
0.411053888,0.199181775,-1,-2,38
0.262232454,0.144137241,-1,-1,74
0.437649773,0.583755593,-1,-2,76
0.71896061,0.147700762,-2,-3,103
0.697941592,0.080480032,-2,-3,77
0.500277498,0.649807717,-3,-4,98
0.437533815,0.006917082,-1,-1,27
0.276252625,0.776412941,0,0,56
0.660321112,0.516544613,-1,-2,94
0.396011967,0.1709671,-2,-3,98
0.539238702,0.703846181,-2,-3,125
0.998578074,0.106352132,-2,-4,184
0.552325405,0.970471559,-3,-5,109
0.380106473,0.948651389,0,0,60
0.887789916,0.328624317,-3,-4,159
```

which I load into a data frame by the standard means:

```
dat <- read.csv("example_data.csv")
```

I'm trying to write a function that will, for a given column name, compute a nls fit, and plot the fit and the data using the given column value as the x value (with a bit of jitter " `+ runif(10,-0.1,0.1)`" to relieve overlap)

```
plotfun <- function (data, parameter) {
  start <- getInitial(Likelihood~SSlogis(substitute(parameter),alpha,xmid,scale),data)
  m <- nls(Likelihood~1/(1+exp((xmid-substitute(parameter))/scale)), start=start[c(2,3)], data=data, weight=Weight)

  pred <- data.frame(substitute(parameter)=seq(min(data$parameter),max(data$parameter),length.out=100))
  pred$y <- predict(m, newdata=pred)

  p <- ggplot (data, aes_q (y=~Likelihood, x=substitute(parameter+runif(10,-0.1,0.1))))
  p + geom_point(size = 1) + geom_line(data=pred, aes_q(x=substitute(parameter),y=~y))
}

plotfun(dat, Par1)
```

But this fails... Basically, I don't understand when I'm supposed to use the bare variable name and where I'm supposed to use `substitute`, or some other function I'm not aware of.

Can someone please explain how to write this function properly?

Comment: One thing for sure is that Par1 is not at this point an object so you would probably want to pass it in as a string.  I think you could simplify the example a great deal, such as I am sure that the jitter has nothing to do with this issue and that you could have just two columns of Par1 and Par2 and maybe 5 rows of data.

Comment: The jitter **does** have to do with the issue, because it's the exact reason I couldn't pass parameter as a string, as you suggested, because I need to do aes_q(x=substitute(parameter + runif(10,-0.1,0.1))

Comment: so the substitue() is working as expected for start<- ?

Comment: I don't know, I can't get the function to 'compile'. It gives an error when it reaches `pred <- data.frame(substitute(parameter)=seq(min(data$parameter),max(data$parameter),length.out=100))`

Comment: I've tested the function only containing `p <- ggplot (data, aes_q (y=~rPath.fraction, x=substitute(parameter+runif(10,-0.1,0.1)))) + geom_pointrange(size = 1)`, but I'm at a loss for how to properly implement the code that does the fitting.

Comment: Where is `rPath.fraction` supposed to come from?

Comment: Sorry MrFlick, missed that in simplification its supposed to be `Likelihood`...

Comment: What what are you trying to do with the geom_pointrange? You're missing a few aesthetics for that to work.

Comment: `data$parameter` certainly won't work unless `data` has a column named literally `parameter`. Use `[` not `$` for subsetting a data frame by column name stored in string. And is it really necessary that you add your own noise manually rather than using ggplot's built-in jitter?

Comment: I would focus on getting the first line to work. But `substitute() ` is not what you are looking for.    parameter should work just fine there.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor. I was unaware of ggplot's position jitter options. Good to know. In this case, perhaps I could use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another answer where you just pass in a string

```
plotfun <- function (data, parameter) {
  data$.var. <- data[,parameter]

  start <- getInitial(Likelihood~SSlogis(.var.,alpha,xmid,scale),data)
  m <- nls(Likelihood~1/(1+exp((xmid-.var.)/scale)), start=start[c(2,3)], data=data, weight=Weight)

  pred <- data.frame(.var. = seq(min(data[,parameter]),max(data[,parameter]),length.out=100))
  pred$y <- predict(m, newdata=pred)

  p <- ggplot (data, aes(y=Likelihood, x=.var.+runif(74,-0.1,0.1)))
  p + geom_point() + geom_line(data=pred, aes(x=.var., y=y)) + xlab(parameter)
}
library(ggplot2)
plotfun(dat, "Par1")
```

We just make a column named `.var.` to make most of the coding much easier, and just change the x label at the end.

Comment: I like this one a lot better! Feels more elegant in a way. Though still nice to know the approach in your previous answer. Let me know if I can buy you a beer for your troubles!

Answer (score 1):

R does not do text-based substitution macros like SAS does or the C compiler. When you need to build expressions you need to make sure they are of the right type so R knows which values to evaluate and which not to. If you have a bunch of places you want to replace a certain symbol with another symbol, then you can use `substitute`. Here's a re-write of your function.

```
plotfun <- function (data, parameter) {
  p <- substitute(parameter)
  expr <- substitute({
    start <- getInitial(Likelihood~SSlogis(parameter,alpha,xmid,scale),data)
    m <- nls(Likelihood~1/(1+exp((xmid-parameter)/scale)), start=start[c(2,3)], data=data, weight=Weight)

    pred <- setNames(data.frame(seq(min(data$parameter),max(data$parameter),length.out=100)), as.character(expression(parameter)))
    pred$y <- predict(m, newdata=pred)

    p <- ggplot (data, aes(y=Likelihood, x=parameter+runif(74,-0.1,0.1)))
    p + geom_line(data=pred, aes(x=parameter,y=y))
  }, list(parameter=p))
  eval(expr)
}
```

Since you want to perform non-standard evaluation by passing an unevaulated symbol to your function, you need to so some extra work. Here we use `substitute()` on the parameter `parameter` to capture the symbol that's in that parameter's promise. Then we use `substitute()` to replace all the occurrences in a block of code of `parameter` with whatever you passed in. Then we `eval()` that new code block.

There one weird thing is there is that you named arguments of functions (as in the `a` of `data.frame(a=1)` aren't proper symbols in the way that `substitute()` would see them. They are named parameters. So we essentially depress the symbol we've passed in and use `setNames()` with that character value to make it work.

So basically I just used substitute twice, once to capture the unevaluated symbol passed to the function, and then to re-write the code in a block. Then I also just used `aes()` rather than `aes_q()`

As easier approach probably would have been to pass in the column names as a string. There are often better alternatives for dynamically building code with character values than symbols.

Comment: Well, the code certainly works! So there is that. Can you explain or give me links to the "easier approach" using strings, as you suggested?

Comment: (To answer your earlier question, in reality the weights were based on errors, so I was using `geom_pointrange` with those error ranges and forgot to change it to `geom_point` when I removed the ranges for the example).

Comment: Honestly you are doing a lot of complicated stuff. The easiest would have been to probably just copy the column of interest to a new column with a fixed name. Then you could write all the code with a non-dynamic name and just change the display to use the right label. Perhaps I can add a separate answer.